# UITableView not displaying content when its parent is not UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In XCode 5, when you add a **UITableViewController** with more than 1 prototype cell which all contain labels etc., the content is displayed because the **UITableViewController** automatically sets the data source and delegate of the table view and sends a *reloadData* message to it.

[iOS Developer Library - Basics of Table View Creation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW5)

But when you drag a **UITableView** to a **UIViewController** I believe you have to create instance methods similar to the default ones below in order for the content to be reloaded and made visible.

*My question is how can I target a **UITableView** somewhere within a **UIViewController** and set its data source and delegate and have it reloaded and its content displayed properly?*

Here is the default code for the UITableViewController:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Here is my code that works with UITableViewController but not in UIViewController for the UITableView that it contains:

```
...

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *menuItems;

...

- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.menuItems = @[@"rowOne", @"rowTwo", @"rowThree", @"rowFour"];
}

...

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.menuItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you tie delegate and dataSource properties to your view controller?

Answer (score 1):

IN your code where u have created your cell if it not exists? And also make cell identifier as static.

You should create cell if it not exists in cellForRowAtINdexPath like as following:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
     if(cell == nil)
       {
        //Create your cell
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }


     //Configure your cell

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The way you implemented, CellIdentifier is not correct as you are referencing object from menuItems array not defining static NSString cell identifier.

Comment: oh yes. Thanks for noticing. actually i forgot to remove this while copying from question. see my edited ans.

Answer (score 0):

You can set data source and delegate in a few ways. If you add table view to view controller in storyboard just control drag from table view to view controller and select delegate and do it again and select data source.
You can also create outlet and in your view controller in viewDidLoad do it by:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

The other way is create table view in code and add it to your view controller view. You can do it in viewDidLoad like that:

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(TABLE_VIEW_FRAME) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

If you want to reload the data just call:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful. I created an outlet to set data source and delegate in storyboard by right-click dragging from the UITableView to the UIViewController and it worked fine. I'm learning XCode at very fast rate. Thanks for showing me how to do it by code and by using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols and set these in the `initWithNibName` or `initWithCoder` initializers.

This is how your .h file should look like:

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Here is what you need to do in the .m file:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

if you are using `storyboards`, please use `initWithCode` as given below:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
     self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        if (self) {
            self.tableView.delegate = self;
            self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        }
        return self;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are only dequeuing the cell but you are not creating one if dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil. You should implement in following way.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// here you can configure the cell
return cell
```